# Identical Inputs in SDK-style project fails to set Printer paper size but Framework-style project works

Tags: c#, printing, system.drawing

Using the System.Drawing.Printing namespace, to set the Paper Size of a document, the `PaperSize PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize { get; set; }` property is used. When printing in an SDK-style project, the Paper Size for the document is never actually set.

The behavior I observe, looking at printed result and driver debug logs is as follows:

1. The printed output is the same size as the printer drivers default, as seen in Control Panel > Devices & Printers > (RightClick) My Label Printer > Printer Preferences > Paper Size.

   - This value is FormName = "Custom", Width = 300, Height = 200. These values correspond to dmFormName, dmPaperLength, and dmPaperWidth respectively in the [DEVMODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-devmodea) of the printer driver
2. The Driver logs indicate the DevMode input was generated from the global default as defined previously.
3. The `PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea { get; }` property was not updated by the driver upon setting the PaperSize in the SDK-style project, but *was* updated in the Framework-style project. In the SDK-project case, this property was using the previously defined 300x200 value.

   - **This is the most easily observable behavior of them all, and should be sufficient to confirm recreation.**

Output for Framework-Style: `{X=0,Y=0,Width=200,Height=100}`

Output for SDK-Style: `{X=0,Y=0,Width=300,Height=200}`

---

Why does the behavior change when the only difference is the project definition? The assembly used to access the namespace appears to be the same, the logic is unchanged, and the target framework is identical. **What broke?**

#### Printing Logic

The logic between the two projects are identical, differing only in namespace. MainWindow holds a single button, which on click fires the same print, a light gray rectangle that fills the image boundary.

```
MainWindow.xaml
---
<Window x:Class="SDK472.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Print" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
---

MainWindow.xaml.cs
---
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Windows;

namespace SDK472
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string AssemblyName { get; } = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;

        public System.Drawing.Bitmap Image { get; set; }

        public void Print()
        {
            PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument()
            {
                PrintController = new StandardPrintController(),
                DocumentName = $"Label {AssemblyName}"
            };

            doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "My Label Printer";
            doc.PrinterSettings.Copies = 1;

            // 0x100 is selected for custom paper size.
            doc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource.RawKind = 0x100;
            doc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom", 200, 100)
            {
                RawKind = 0x100
            };

            Debug.WriteLine(doc.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.ToString());
            doc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;

            Image = new Bitmap(600, 300);
            using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(Image))
            {
                using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xee, 0xee, 0xee)))
                {
                    gfx.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, 600, 300);
                }
            }

            doc.PrintPage += PrintCallback;

            doc.Print();
        }

        public void PrintCallback(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            RectangleF printArea = e.PageSettings.Bounds;

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image, 0, 0, printArea.Width, printArea.Height);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Print();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Project Setup

Behavior was recreated with two new projects, created in the following manner:

[image: Framework Start]

- The "Framework" project created with default settings; named "Legacy472". Full source for the .csproj is default, but will not be displayed here for brevity.

[image]

- The "SDK" project, created with default settings then retargeted to 472; named "SDK472"

```
SDK472.csproj:
---
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

#### System.Drawing References

The major difference I noticed between the two projects, was the Properties sheet for the System.Drawing reference, though both reference the same .dll.

##### The Legacy Properties

[image]

##### The SDK Properties

### [image]

Comment: To me, if you have a default (say, Letter or A4) size after you have set custom PageSize and `PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea` is *rounded* to pixel values, the Printer is refusing the Custom page settings -- Not clear why you don't have `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` in your Project file -- Side note: you should aways set the `RawKind` to, e.g., `(int)PaperKind.Custom`, because this value can change without notice

Comment: @Jimi, you were correct, the printer driver was refusing my settings. The reason appears to be word-size issues when targeting a 64-bit platform vs. 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

The DEVMODE struct seems to have only been valid with 32-bit values. The printer driver was rejecting an incorrectly marshaled pointer and using default values instead.

Inspecting the Framework-style project, it has the following properties set by default:
[image]

The fix was to add this line to the SDK-style project:

`<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>`

After forcing the platform target to 32-bit, the print was correctly sent and all 3 behaviors matched between Framework-Style and SDK-style projects.